# When to use 洗濯する and 洗う？

Tags: word-choice, verbs

今日ふくを洗う。
今日ふくを洗濯する。

昨日食器を洗った。
昨日食器を洗濯した。

I know that 洗濯する means: washing or laundering (clothes). And 洗う just means washing. When I'm talking about washing in general can I use the two words interchangeably? When do I have to use one word as opposed to the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(I moved my old comment to this answer with more detail.)

洗う is a verb and 洗濯 is a noun.  I assume that you want to compare 洗う and 洗濯する, which are both verbs.

When you are talking about washing *in general*, you cannot use 洗濯する because 洗濯する is only for washing *clothes* (as you wrote by yourself!).  For example, it is incorrect to say 食器を洗濯する.

Comment: Well I wrote: washing OR laundering clothes. I thought 洗濯 and 洗濯する could be used in both ways, since that's how the dictionaries define 洗濯. [Here's an example.](http://www.eudict.com/?lang=japeng&word=sentaku) And yes, I did mean 洗濯する. Thank you.

Comment: @dotnetN00b: (1) Ah, I see. I had read “washing or laundering clothes” as “[washing or laundering] clothes,” which is why I wrote “as you wrote by yourself”.  (2) You might want to buy some Japanese-English dictionary for learners of Japanese.  An online dictionary which defines 洗濯 as just “washing, laundry” is obviously insufficient to learn Japanese.

Comment: Or use a better online dictionary: [EDICT](http://jisho.org/words?jap=sentaku&eng=&dict=edict) at least lists 洗濯 as noun **and** "Suru verb" and has 80 [example sentences](http://jisho.org/sentences/) containing the word 洗濯.

Comment: @user1205935 Your example sentences didn't work. Also, when I used it to look up sentaku, I got the same definitions as I got with the other site.

Comment: Yes, but you have more information about the word. It says 洗濯 Noun, Suru verb, Common word. The sentences you need to enter in Japanese, either per copy-and-paste or per Japanese IME. I couldn't paste a Unicode URL as link, but if you copy-and-paste the following link, you should be able to see the example sentences: `http://jisho.org/sentences?jap=洗濯&eng=`

Comment: @dotnebN00b: I am not sure about American English but in Britain when we wash the dishes we "do the washing-up" and when washing clothes we "do the washing". If you look up "washing-up" (or "dish-washing") in the dictionary you refer us to (EUdict) then you will get "saraarai". Possibly a whole new "spin" on the phrase "two countries divided by a common language"? (Sorry, I could not resist the pun.)

Comment: @Tim So a dishwasher is さらあらいき? :)

Comment: My dictionary says: ディッシュウオッシャー〖dishwasher〗
自動食器洗い機 but I think people will understand ;)